# HTML video/audio crashes on multiple load ups

Tags: html, video, audio, crash, load

I have an application with multiple thumbnails (10+) and have manually set up onMouseEnter/Leave to load up a video/audio file like so

```
onMouseEnter=function(){
    videoPlayer.pause();
    videoPlayer.src=that.videoPath;
    videoPlayer.play()
}
```

It works fine, but if I move the mouse too quickly, it crashes. I tried using `setTimeOut()` with a 1s delay and using `clearTimeout()` to prevent interference, but the problem still persisted.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks